# xCode: "Property access result unused" when trying to make key window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, button, window

(I'm using xCode 7.0.1 on El Capitan)

So I have a main window and a button there and I also have another window which is not visible at first. The idea is to click the button and make the main window close and at the same time make the other window key and order it to front.
Here's my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)makeNewWindow:(id)sender {
    _newWindow.makeKeyWindow;
    _window.close;
}
```

However, when I enter this code, xCode gives me a warning saying "property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects".

I tried looking for the reason the error pops up but none of the questions were related to mine.

**NOTE:** I am not linking the button to the two windows because if I do, it only keeps the task last given and does not complete the previous one.

Any thoughts on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around for a few minutes I ended up with this piece of code that works. (Credit to @zaph for helping)

```
- (IBAction)makeNewWindow:(id)sender {
    [self.window close];
    [self.newWindow orderFront:(_newWindow)];
}
```

Comment: `[self.newWindow orderFront:(_newWindow)]` can't be right. `[self.newWindow orderFront:sender]` or `[self.newWindow orderFront:self]` is better.

Comment: @Willeke Surprisingly enough it works. I am kinda confused myself about this too.

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation (`_newWindow.becomeKeyWindow`) is meant to be used to access properties, not to call methods, particularly methods that have side effects.

Instead use method calling syntax:

```
[self.newWindow becomeKeyWindow];
```

It really is best, a best practice, to use `self.` (`self.newWindow`) when using properties, not the variable directly with a leading underscore (`_newWindow`).

Comment: This does make my main window disappear but it doesn't bring the second window to the front. Main Window: [self.mainWindow close]; ||  and for the second window: [self.newWindow makeKeyWindow]; || What am I missing?

Comment: That s a separate issue and question. Without more code that is difficult to answer. Suggestion: Open a new question about that.